# How many circuits can I put on a 70A breaker?

Tags: electrical

If I pull off of my 200 amp main panel a 4/3 wire for a 70 amp breaker to my sub panel, how many circuits can I run without the breaker tripping?

I need:

- 4-20 amp breakers for a microwave, frig, 120v stove and small air/heater combo unit
- 1-30 amp breaker for a a pool pump
- 2- 15 amp breakers for lighting

Is there any problem in doing this?

Comment: That's not a valid question. Circuits don't trip breakers. Loads do.

Comment: You can run 100 circuits, each to a device that pulls 70 amps, but you can only run 1 of those devices at a time. You can run 70 circuits that each serve a 1 amp load and run them all at once. Or, you could run a lighting circuit (probably w/a 20amp breaker) that will serve all your LED lighting needs, 2 or 3 circuits on 20 amp breakers for general plug in loads, and a dedicated 50amp circuit for charging your EV. You just won't be able to charge the car, run all the lights and use the microwave and coffee maker all at the same time.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't worded correctly ... 4-20 amp breakers, 1-30 amp breaker and 2- 15 amp breakers ...which in terms is micro, frig, 120v stove and small air/heater combo unit on the 20's... pool pump is on the 30 amp and the 15 amps for lighting circuits ..

Comment: And by the way Freeman,  I appreciate ur response , thank you

Comment: Is  the pool pump the only 240v load?

Comment: Yes it is the only 240v load on it

Comment: Your location in the world may have more to do with what the answer really is. What freeman has commented is true but if governed by the national electric code it would not be code compliant. The type of circuits makes a difference and residential or commercial use. My dads Garage was a commercial wood shop so there were limits to the number of receptacles per circuit and the total size of the service it required for those loads. A regular garage non commercial there can be more receptacles on a circuit than commercial. But the only way to know for sure is with the location and the types loads

Comment: I've included the important details from your comment in the original question. If I don't have it quite right, click the [edit] button below your post and fix it up. If someone asks for additional detail (like where in the world you're located), you can [edit] that into your original question, too. People don't always read all the comments and they can get deleted, so vital info like that can get lost.

Comment: What you have described will likely not trip the 70a breaker. Is there a bathroom? Water heater? A sink in the same room as cooking?

Comment: I hope you didn't just buy 4-3 copper wire for that... 4-3+ground aluminum would have sufficed for 1/3 the cost, or 6-3+ground copper of certain types (not NM or UF).

Comment: @Javier How many HP is the pool pump? Also, can you get us make/model or nameplate info for the air-conditioner/heater combo unit, and how many square feet of floor area does this panel serve for general lighting and receptacle loads?